# Tensor Question

Tags: tensor-calculus, propagator

When looking for a massive vector boson propagator, one needs to invert the relationship

$[(-k^2 +m^2)g^{\mu\alpha}+k^{\alpha}k^{\mu}]D_{\mu\lambda} = \delta_{\lambda}^{\alpha}$.

Here $D_{\mu\lambda}$ is the propagator. My question is, why can't we just write $k^{\alpha}k^{\mu} = g^{\mu\alpha}k^{\alpha}k_{\alpha} = g^{\mu\alpha}k^2$. So that we now have to invert

$[(-k^2 +m^2)g^{\mu\alpha}+g^{\alpha \mu}k^2]D_{\mu\lambda} = \delta_{\lambda}^{\alpha}$.

$[m^2g^{\mu\alpha}]D_{\mu\lambda} = \delta_{\lambda}^{\alpha}$.

Obviously, this propagator is not dynamic so it can't be correct but this indicates that I have made a mistake in using $k^{\alpha}k^{\mu} = g^{\mu\alpha}k^{\alpha}k_{\alpha} = g^{\mu\alpha}k^2$. But I don't see from a mathematical perspective why this is incorrect.

Comment: Hint: $g^{\mu\alpha} k^\alpha k_\alpha$ contains 3 "$\alpha$". Can we have triple indices in Einstein convention?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I think I understand. In making the substitution, I have lost the off diagonal elements or the $k^{\mu}k^{\alpha}$ tensor.

Comment: @Noiralef I see the problem with the indices. Thank you both!